# Can I force Heroku to compile the assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I used to develop a project on my own and now I have got some others to help in the project. It's developed with Ruby on Rails and we have a staging server on Heroku. Beforehand the deployment workflow is to precompile the assets in local machine then push the code to heroku. It works well when I am on my own.

Now I am working with a Front-end engineer. The problem is we are working in different location so it is difficult to setup his computer the same as mine. As a result, he will not be able to precompile the code before pushing to heroku.

Of course I can do it for him but would be better if he can just submit the code to the staging server and let Heroku to precompile it. I think Heroku detect if the `manifest` file is available to determine if it needs to precompile. Is there a way to force Heroku to recompile the assets?

I have tried: `heroku run rake assets:clean` then `heroku run rake assets:precompile` but no luck...

Comment: Heroku should be able to precompile your assets when it builds your slug. Have you read through https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline ?

Comment: Thanks Fred, I have heard of this before but in the doc, it did not show how to force Heroku to run precompile. Do you know how I can do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Heroku's servers use a [read-only file system](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem). This is how they make it easy for you to spin up more dynos, among other things.

Compiling Rails assets means taking the source files and compiling a new file, i.e. writing a file to the file system. Since this can't happen on a read-only file system, you have to precompile first. Even if you did manage to compile assets on Heroku, by writing to the /tmp directory, at the end of the day when [Heroku reboots dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting), your new files will be gone because they weren't checked into the repo as they would've been if you had precompiled them locally, committed them, and then pushed to Heroku.

Any workaround I can imagine would be more complicated than helping your front end dev setup Rails and bundle installing the gems needed to precompile before pushing.